# How to build custom URL by adding ?&params in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to build a custom URL and update the URL as the user selects items in my dashboard.

For example, after clicking a few items the URL could/should look like:

`#/dashboard?&portfolio=GOOG&ticker1=GOOG`

Currently the URL only ends in `/dashboard` (`console.log($location.path());`)

How would I update the `$location.path()` to add params like so? There's plenty of questions/answers and guides on getting params from the URL, but how would you update the URL in the first place?

Say if you want to add the following:

- `?&portfolio=GOOG&ticker1=GOOG`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just organize your params in an object, like

```
var params = {
   portfolio: GOOG,
   ticker1:GOOG
}
```

and use,

```
$location.url('/dashboard ').search(params);
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Cool I see this! `#/dashboard?portfolio=GOOG&ticker1=GOOG`

Comment: That wouldn't be a valid query string if you did that

Comment: I like this solution as it does exactly what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a custom query string that I can bookmark and read back in the properties when the link is shared.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm understanding what you're saying. I believe you could use a PHP GET function to do that. A GET function in PHP will add the information you're trying to communicate to the backend to the URL, while the POST function does not.